# How should xit() be used in relation to describe() and it() in jest?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I understand describe() and it() in jest but I have following queries on xit():

- How should xit() be used along with describe() and it()?

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/api#testskipname-fn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Speaking for myself, I use `xit()` when I want to temporarily disable that specific test. Running the test will only report that the `xit()` exists, therefore documenting it and reminding me, but it won't actually run the test.

Later, when I'm otherwise done making changes, I either delete that part of the test or change it back to `it()` as appropriate.